# Docker - Windows Container - Install DotNet Framework 472

Tags: .net, powershell, docker, chocolatey, windows-container

I am trying to setup a Windows Docker image with .net framework 4.7.2. 
For other reasons, I am starting from **microsoft/windowsservercore**

What I tried so far 
- I have choco installed on my image, so my initial solution was to use choco install

```
choco install dotnet4.7.2 --allow-empty-checksums -y -v --trace -d
```

What I get is 0x80004005

```
C:\users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey> more .\dd_NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU_decompression_log.txt
??[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] === Logging started: 2019/05/25 22:26:33 ===
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Executable: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\dotnetfx\4.7.2.20180712\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe v4.7.3081.0
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Successfully bound to the ClusApi.dll
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Error 0x800706d9: Failed to open the current cluster
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Cluster drive map: ''
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Considering drive: 'C:\'...
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Drive 'C:\' has been selected as the largest fixed drive
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Directory 'C:\b659e2a87b51ccf0f10d6292d1a4c2\' has been selected for file extraction
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Extracting files to: C:\b659e2a87b51ccf0f10d6292d1a4c2\
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files out of box container #0.
[5/25/2019, 22:26:33] Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract
```

- Looking for 0x80004005 , I found some similar issues 
  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4808233e-1410-4305-a8d1-0e88f3a6fdc8/net-451-install-only-works-when-running-on-a-ui-session?forum=configmanagerapps

https://blog.nowmicro.com/2015/02/23/deploying-net-framework-4-5-2-configmgr-application/

Following some the ideas from links above, I did :

1. I downloaded manually NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
2. I extracted it locally, on host, from command line (with /extract). Basically I have a local directory with all content of the NDP472 (including
   Setup.exe)
3. I am running the container using volume

**docker run --name cw10 -v C:\MyNDP472:C:\tmp -d client-windows10**

4. I am attaching to the container with cmd. From C:\tmp (which points to C:\MyNDP472 from host), I am running from command line.

**Setup.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage "ADMINDEPLOYMENT" /x86 /x64 /redist /log "C:\tmp\reportdotnet.log"**

5. The result is **Final Result: Installation completed successfully with success code: (0x80070BC2), "The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted**.

[image]

6. I am checking the registries (this time with Powershell)

**Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |Get-ItemProperty -name Version,Release -EA 0 |Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |Select PSChildName, Version, Release**

7. I still get previous version of .net framework  (Full 4.6.01586  394802) - the one that comes with the base image.
   I reboot the container with docker restart. I get exactly the same. No changes.

My final goal : I want to build a C# sln solution with target 4.7.2.

I am out of ideas. 
Any thought?

Thanks

Comment: Look for docker file which Microsoft using for their dotnet framework

Comment: @GregorySuvalian  - is this available ? github I guess..

Comment: Yes, it's on GitHub, you need just find it

Comment: For future reference - although I still need to validate it - https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/4.7.2/sdk/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile.

Comment: This is SDK image, you need runtime

Comment: Actually I am planning to do some building of a solution. I forgot to mention this in the description. My bad.

Comment: @silverb77: please amend the question to reflect whatever you have forgotten. Since you have not yet gotten any answers, you can rewrite the question, rather than adding an "update" addendum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this without using an existing image, then you could create a powershell script to download and install it, and then call this from within your dockerfile:

```
Write-Host ".Net 4.7.2 not installed. Downloading..."
Invoke-WebRequest "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863265" -OutFile "NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
Write-Host "Installing .Net 4.7.2..."
$exe = ".\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
&$exe /q /norestart
```

The DockerFile (assuming you name your script InstallNetFramework.ps1 and it lives in the same folder as your DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore 
RUN mkdir c:\install
ADD /InstallNetFramework.ps1 c:\install
RUN powershell c:\install\InstallNetFramework.ps1
```

But you are probably best using an image that already has .Net 4.7.2 installed because otherwise:

- It's going to be slow every time you need to build your image (waiting for it to d/l and install .Net 4.7.2 every time)
- You are going to need to update the download path should microsoft patch 4.7.2 in the future or move the download etc.

If you just do this once however, you could register this in your own personal Container Registry and use it as your base image for further DockerFiles (e.g. use this as the FROM)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same dockerfile which microsoft using for building their dotnetframework images here for SDK (https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/4.7.2/sdk/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile) or runtime (https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/4.7.2/runtime/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile)

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Thank you. However, I would be [also] interested if someone is able to provide a solution that starts from microsoft/windowsservercore

Comment: Microsoft dockerfile is starting from windowsservercore. What do you mean by your question?